# AttributeError: 'Type' object has no attribute '_state' django

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I am trying to build my first project in Django. This is my code for the blog category model. I have already registered it the admin file, but I don't know why it threw this error.

```
# blog categories
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name ='category'
        verbose_name_plural ='categories'
```

Error message:

```
  File "E:\installs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 116, in __get__
    instance, refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name]) 
  File "E:\installs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 684, in refresh_from_db
    db = using if using is not None else self._state.db 
AttributeError: 'Type' object has no attribute '_state' 
[17/May/2018 14:55:31] "GET /admin/blog/type/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 131993
```

Comment: Wrong indentation inside class Meta

Comment: Yeah, thats a mistake i made when pasting the code. its well indented in my editor

Comment: The exception trace is not complete, can you paste it?

Comment: File "E:\installs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 116, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name])
  File "E:\installs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 684, in refresh_from_db
    db = using if using is not None else self._state.db
AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute '_state'
[17/May/2018 15:19:49] "GET /admin/quiz/category/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132166

Comment: Have you migrate your models?

Comment: Yeah. i have already run the two commands  makemigrations and migrate .  But i dont understand where the attribute state comes from in the error

Comment: Is that the only code in the Category class?? Are you overriding the __init__ method?

Comment: yeah. that the only code. have not override any init method

Comment: do the Category model class has or had "state" field? possibly it is just a migration's error

Comment: Nope there is filed state neither in the post nor the category class

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was just my silly mistake 
**def __init__(self):
        return self.name**

I was using **init** instead of **str ....but why would this one cause an error like an attribute error like that 
**def __str**(self):
        return self.name**

Thanks ,my bad

Comment: You say in a comment that you "have not override any init method" and now you talk of a `__init__` method that's not in your question. This question is incomplete.